# Problem with variables in prolog

Tags: variables, scope, prolog, global-variables

```
     num(N) :- No=N, write(No), nl.

     check(S) :- No==S -> write(Ok) ; write(Not ok).
```

When i call `num(5)`, it prints 5. However after calling `num(5)`, when i call `check(5)`, it prints Not ok. I think its because of scope of variables..How can i make it work, i mean variable No like a global variable, so that i can check its value in other clauses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the [global variables](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%276.3%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/gvar.html%27%29%29) of swipl or assert/retract

however, using global variables is a bit against the declarative programming paradigm since it violates referential transparency

Comment: What do you mean by referential transparency?

Comment: @svick [http://bit.ly/jVCut9] basically it means that a function will behave like a math function: it will return the same result if given the same arguments.

Comment: In gnu prolog there is no such thing i guess.

Comment: @thetux4 I haven't used gnu-prolog :/ I wouldn't be surprised if there aren't any global variables but are you sure that there is no library with assert/retract?

Comment: @thanosQR, after reading gnu-prolog manual, assert and retract are defined, so i used them and they worked. Also, there is g_assign function to manipulate global variables but i couldn't make it work, though.

Comment: @thetux4 nice d: basically the global variables are just faster so it's not a big deal in most cases

Answer (score 1):

There's no global variable in Prolog. If you need a variable in all the clauses, pass it as an argument in those clauses. For example, you use:

```
check(S, N0) :- N0==S -> write('Ok') ; write('Not ok').
```

and call `check(5, 5)` or `check(S, 5)` as you want.